# Issue with kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have defined kendocombox in my html like below

```
<input  id="selFrameworkVersion" style="width: 210px" data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'Id', data:  $root.versionListByProductType, value:  $root.editFrameworkVersion, optionsCaption: 'Select Version...'  }" />
```

The combobox loads correctly and sets value but when it doesnt set focus to proper item in list. See image below
[image: Kendobox]

You can see value is 5.5.1 but it sets to 5.4 which is first item in list. 
I now know that why its happening. On my combobox you can see that i have value set as $root.editFrameworkVersion. In my view model i use subscribe event on that value. See code below

```
self.editFrameworkVersion.subscribe(function (value) {
        var combobox = $("#selFrameworkVersion").data("kendoComboBox");

        var callback = function (data) {

            self.editOnlyAlternativeVersions(self.versionListByProductType());

            combobox.select(function (dataItem) {
               return dataItem.Name === value;
            });
            self.editOnlyAlternativeVersions.remove(function (data) {

                return parseInt($("#selFrameworkVersion").attr('value')) === parseInt(data.Id()); 
            });


        };

        loadVersionListByProductType(self.editProductType().Id(), callback);
```

});

I use this subscribe event to do some logic. In this event i am calling WCF service which loads value again in that combobox and thats why its always set to first value. But its required for me to call that service for some logic. Then i added code in that subscribe event which you already have seen above

```
combobox.select(function (dataItem) {
               return dataItem.Name === value;
            });
```

This code sets the value correctly but only if combobox loses focus. What should i do?

Comment: is this part of kendo ui available in open source? I'm a little reluctant to just download their open source .js and try to replicate locally instead of being able to just include a web uri straight into jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes its open source. No harm

Comment: it's open source but not publically available, I don't want to download it currently.

Answer (score 0):

In the [ComboBox demo here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html) they use an `index` property to set the initially selected item. Not sure if you can try that in your case. Otherwise there is also a [.select() method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#select) that you can call on the widget to set the selected item.

It does seem odd that it doesn't set the selected item based on the `value`. Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: Please help. Its not working. I tried all method you mentioned in your link but none is working

Comment: ok now i know why its not working but dont know solution for it. I am using subscribe function on the value defined in combobox. The value is editFrameworkVersion and i am using subscribe function on that value.

Comment: Please help. I have also edited my questions with more findings. I am really struggline a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
$("#selFrameworkVersion").attr("autofocus",true);

Comment: unfortunately i am not using kendo combobox anymore. Many thanks for your reply.