# Set item name from combobox to knockout list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one issue displaying value from combobox to knockout list.
Please image below where i am selecting item from combobox. When i select item from combobox it updates all the rows with same value.
[image: List with same values]

The list on left hand side doesnt store name from combobox in database but it stores id. So combobox and list is connected with column called Status. In my html i have defined list as below where ChangeControlName is the one which i want to bind to list

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: versionDataByProduct">

    <tr data-bind="click: $root.EditVersionDetail, css: { selected: isSelected}"   >

        <td data-bind="text: Name "></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Code"></td>
        <td data-bind ="text: PlatformVersionName"></td>
        <td data-bind ="text: ChangeControlName"></td>
      </tr>
```

The combox is loaded as below in my viewmodel

```
     // Load Change Control List
    function loadChangeControlList() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../RestService/Product/ChangeControlList",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            },
            success: function (allData) {
                var mappedChangeControls = $.map(allData, function (item) {

                    return new changeControlList(item);
                });
                self.ChangeControls(mappedChangeControls);

            }
        });
    }
```

I have binded my combobox in html as below

```
<td><select id="selModuleType"  data-bind="options: $root.modules,  optionsCaption: 'Please select Module...' , value: $root.editModuleId , optionsText: 'ModuleName'" /></td>
```

When i select row on left hand side shown in image above i get selectedrow. On subscribe event of value editModuleId  i try to assign value to selected row as below.

```
self.editChangeControl.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        self.selecteditem().ChangeControlId(value.Status());

        self.selecteditem().ChangeControlName(value.ChangeControl());

    });
```

In the code above selecteditem contains the row we selected. ChangeControlId as you can see above in the code is the id of value we select from combobox and this is set correctly to the list. But name is not set correctly. The reason being that ChangeControlId is stored in database. The ChangeControlId is part of table from where these rows are shown. ChangeControlName i want for just display purpose. What should i do? I also tried using computed observable but it shows as "object object" in the list. I used computed observable as below

```
       this.ChangeControlName = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                debugger;
                return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ChangeControls(), function (item) {
                    if (item.Status() === productVersionId.ChangeControlId()) {
                        return item.ChangeControl();
                    }
                });
            },

            write: function (value) {
                console.log("Value i get " + value);
                return value;
            }
        });
```

Comment: is there a jsfiddle or jsbin for this?

Comment: no i dont have any fiddle for this.but do you understand my issue?

Comment: I'm trying to follow it. Do you want to save the updated value on the left for change control back to the db while still just displaying the description in a label instead of the raw id?

Comment: i just want to display name which has been selected in combobox. I save id correctly. Its only that i am not able to set the value correctly in list to what has been selected in combobox

Comment: so when an item on the left is selected, and they change the box on the right, just that one selected row on the left should change the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, the design you have makes it very difficult to get where you want to go.

```
var VersionModel = function () {
  var self = this;

  self.changeControls = ko.observable([{
    name: "Addressed",
    value: 1
  }, {
    name: "Not Addressed",
    value: 2

  }]);

  console.log(self.changeControls()[0].value);
  self.versionDataByProduct = [{
    Name: "DS",
    Code: "sd",
    PlatformVersionName: "5.5.3",
    ChangeControl: ko.observable(self.changeControls()[0]),
  }, {
    Name: "EF",
    Code: "sd",
    PlatformVersionName: "5.5.3",
    ChangeControl: ko.observable(self.changeControls()[0])
  }];
  self.selected = ko.observable(self.versionDataByProduct[0]);
  self.EditVersionDetail = function (item) {

    self.selected(item);
  };
  self.editModuleId = ko.observable();
  self.modules = [{
    editModuleId: 1,
    ModuleName: "ABW-BP-Batch Input"
  }];

  self.editChangeControl = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
      if (self.selected()) {
          console.log('something selected and editChangeControl is changing');
        return self.selected().ChangeControl();
      }
      return '';
    },
    write: function (value) {
      if (value && value != '') {
          console.log('writing new value');
        self.selected().ChangeControl(value);
      }
    }
  });

}
ko.applyBindings(new VersionModel());
```

and the html:

```
<table class="floatLeft">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Version name</th>
      <th>Version Code</th>
      <th>Framework version</th>
      <th>Change control</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: versionDataByProduct">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.EditVersionDetail, css: { selected: $root.selected() == $data}">
      <td data-bind="text: Name "></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Code"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: PlatformVersionName"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: ChangeControl().name,attr:{'data-value':ChangeControl().value}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<select id="selModuleType" data-bind="options: $root.modules,  optionsCaption: 'Please select Module...' , value: $root.editModuleId , optionsText: 'ModuleName'"></select>
<select id="selfChangeControl" data-bind="options: $root.changeControls,  optionsCaption: 'Please select Change control...' , value: editChangeControl , optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Khk3/4/

Comment: What a perfect example. You are master really. Hope i learn something from you. Do you know what can be more better way to achieve this?

Comment: Also are you able to help on this. I am really really struggling past 3 days   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611768/issue-with-kendo-combobox

Comment: There is one issue here. In the list while loading you have set as ChangeControl: ko.observable(self.changeControls()[0]). This always select similar values. Suppose my list are already saved with different values. In our fiddle example it will be like value 1 and value 2. Now what is happening is that suppose my list are preloaded with value 1 and 2 and  change first value in list to 2 and try to select first row then it sets back to 1. Did you got my point?

Comment: I loaded it with the data you showed in your screenshot, you would load it according to your actual use case.

Comment: Actually because of line 
      ChangeControl: ko.observable(self.changeControls()[0])
it loads first value. What should i do for it?